# Как реализовать переключение между страницами?

Tags: jquery, ajax, html, css

Это единственное решение в интернете.

Как в этом плагине: https://0.s3.envato.com/files/27577254/index.html#/homepage

Как такое реализовать?

Comment: Я уточню, что на новых версия jquery он не работает, как исправить это?

Answer (score 1):

[Этот плагин](http://stolksdorf.github.io/Parallaxjs/) подойдет?